# Vue.js [v-cloak] does not use CSS transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

**My Intention:**

Using the Vue.js (v2) attribute [v-cloak], I want to have the "app" hidden until ready. When [v-cloak] is removed, I want the "app" to fade in. Using CSS opacity and transitions to achieve the fade.

**The Problem:**

When [v-cloak] is removed from my "app" there is no transition as I would expect. It just goes from hidden to visible immediately. Seems to ignore the CSS.

**Example:**

I have made an exaggerated example with Vue.js and a JavaScript simulated version to show how they both behave.

https://codepen.io/freemagee/pen/wXqrRM

When viewing this example, you will see the "Plain old JavaScript" red box fade into view over 5 seconds. But the Vue controlled version just appears without a fade. They share the same CSS for the transition, so in theory should work the same way.

Anyone used [v-cloak] effectively to achieve smooth transitions?

**Codepen Code**

HTML

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <div class="red-box"></div>
  <p>Vue.js {{ message }}</p>
</div>

<div id="app2" v-cloak>
  <div class="red-box"></div>
  <p>Plain old JavaScript</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

[v-cloak] .red-box {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0s 5s, opacity 5s linear;  
}

#app,
#app2{
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.red-box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 5s linear;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello world"
  }
});

window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("app2").removeAttribute("v-cloak");
}, 500);
```

Comment: `v-cloak` is a vue directive, there should be no sign of it on the generated markup

Comment: Hi @Vivick, my experience so far, is that if I do not manually add v-cloak to the app element, then you will see "handlebars" like content whilst Vue does it's thing. I have watched Vue remove the v-cloak directive successfully using Chrome web inspector. But that does not trigger the CSS transition fade in. I really would expect it to. I believe I am doing it the same as this the documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Comment: maybe this will help? https://jsfiddle.net/claudchan/u7x6vx1q/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't work because after the Vue app instance initializes, **the `#app` div is actually removed, re-rendered and becomes a different div**, even though it looks the same. This is probably due to Vue's virtual DOM mechanism.

The `#app2` elements is still the same DOM after `document.getElementById("app2").removeAttribute("v-cloak");`: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/PaKQwV

The `#app` element is a different DOM after `new Vue(...)`: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/ERvojx?editors=0010

For the Vue app, the element with `v-cloak` is removed, another element without `v-cloak` is added back. **There is no element that transition from "with `v-cloak`" to "without `v-cloak`".** That's why the CSS transition won't work. Hope that this is clear enough.

(If you don't already know this, )You can use [Transition Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components)

Comment: Hi @Jacob Goh, thanks for the answer. I have been using <transition> elements in other parts of my real app, but like you say maybe I need to wrap everything up in a higher level <transition>. With regards to v-cloak, I thought there was something going on under the hood as the basic rules of CSS were not working as expected. Good to know I am not going mad!

Answer (score 3):

As explained, there is no transition possible with [v-cloak], as the DOM element without the v-cloak is a new one.

I've figured a simple workaround, using the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) methods and its hook vm.$nextTick(), in which case, the use of v-cloak isn't necessary anymore.

Mounted is called when the original app element has been replaced with the new one generated by Vue, but it doesn't necessarily mean that every child has been rendered yet. nextTick is called when every child element has been rendered inside the app view.

First, I have setup my HTML app element like this :

```
<div id="main-view" :class="{ready: isPageReady}">...</div>
```

In my vue app :

```
new Vue({
    el: "#main-view",
    data: {
        isPageReady: false, 
    [...]
    mounted: function() {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            this.isPageReady = true;
        });
    }
});
```

Finally in the CSS, I tried a simple fadein using opacity:

```
#main-view {
    opacity: 0;
}
#main-view.ready {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Beware: the transition doesn't always show if you have the browser's inspector/debugger open.

Comment: This is similar to what I have done. I have a "isLoading" class on the main app element (shows a spinner). I then update the isLoading "value" (mine is a computed value) when the app is mounted just like you do. Great minds!